# Building a list after preforming an operation on each element of a sepatate list

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x

I have what should be a straight forward task. I have a very large data file from which I want to extract only specific data. What I want do at the start is to read in two columns, call them *mass and snapnum*, divide the first element of *mass* in half then go through the rest of the list and if that number `mass / 2`  is found append that to a new list as well as the corresponding element in the *snapnum* list.

My test data is as follows:

```
///HEADER
1000    400
100     50
200     300
800     400 
50      25
100     300
500     100
400     200
```

Results I expect are

```
 500  100
  50  25
 100  300 
 400  200
```

My try at a code

```
   MASS = []
   MASS2 = []
   SNAPNUM = []

 for line in nlines:             #Loop Strips empty lines as well as replaces          tabs      with space
  if line !='':
  line = line.strip()
  line = line.replace('\t',' ')
  columns = line.split()
  snapnum = columns[1]
  mass = float(columns[0])   
  mass2 = mass/2.;print(mass/2)    #divide element in mass by half.
  if  mass == mass2:    
     MASS2.append(mass2)
     SNAPNUM.append(snapnum)
     continue

print(MASS2)
print(SNAPNUM)
```

The results I get

```
    500.0
    50.0
    100.0
    400.0
    25.0
    50.0
    250.0
    200.0
    []
    []
```

It seems that the MASS2 and SNAPNUM lists are not getting appended. If I change the condition to `if mass <= mass2`  I get appended list but the results are not the ones I want from above. It also seems as if the code just loops through and divides the entire list all at once instead of dividing one element at a time.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `if mass == mass2` is effectively equivalent to `if mass == mass/2.0`. So it's not very surprising to me that your lists are empty. Because 500 does not equal 250, 50 does not equal 25, 100 does not equal 50... etc.

Comment: Also, is that your actual indentation? One space before  `for line in nlines:` and zero spaces before `if line !='':`? Seems like that should crash with an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Indentation got thrown off in the copy and paste.

Comment: @Kevin, what I want is for it to append when the mass/2 == mass, should I just write a separate list will just the mass/2 then compare that to the original list? The real data sets I will be working with are quite large and I worry about memory.

Comment: So you want to append when mass is zero? That's the only number that's equal to itself divided by two. Or are you trying to refer to two different things when you say "mass"? Like "mass of the current line" and "mass of the first line" or something? If so, you should give them separate names like `first_mass` and `current_mass`. Then you can do your comparison like `if current_mass == first_mass/2`.

Comment: Could numpy.where() be used here?

Comment: What happens if you find multiple halves of the same value? Append them both?

Comment: That's okay as all of the halves are associated with other columns that have distinct entries.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that all I needed was a nested loop indexed properly for loop.

```
for line in nlines:           
  if line !='':
     line = line.strip()
     line = line.replace(',',' ')
     columns = line.split()
     snapnum = columns[8]
     mass = float(columns[6])
     MASS.append(mass)
     mass2 = mass/2
     MASS2.append(mass2)
     SNAPNUM.append(snapnum)
     for i in range(N):
       for j in range(i,N):
          if (-0.2)*MASS2[i] <= MASS[j] <= (0.2)*MASS2[i]:
             MASS3.append(MASS2[i])
             SNAPNUM2.append(SNAPNUM[j])
```

I just fear that this is not the most efficient way of doing things.